# Ctypes Issue - Impossible to work with 64-bits DLL versus 32-bits DLL - OSError: exception: access violation reading

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, wrapper, oserror

After many hours of research and topics analysized, I can't find an explication & a way to solve properly my issue.
If you found an answer, thank you very much in advance.

**Summary of my issue**:

I'm working with python 3.8 (64-bits versions) & a dll (64-bits too). And, I can't wrap this one properly into my python code, despite of ctypes capabilities (argstype, restype..etc) due to a pointer issue (from my little understanding).

What is troubling me, is that, the same DLL in 32 bits, with python 32-bits is working well with the my python code.

Please find here after:

- The C Prototype
- The Python Code to Wrap the C function
- The Usage of the C function into the python code

C Function Prototype (from API description):
*WORD mpc_AddToScenarioPcd (BYTE, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, POINTER(BYTE), DWORD, POINTER(BYTE), VOID**)

**My Python Code to wrap this one (64 bits version & 32 bits version commented) :**

```
from ctypes import *

# DLL Loading ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 64 Bits -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dllpath = '%s/MP300Com64.dll' % str(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MP300Dll = WinDLL(dllpath)
MP300Dll_CDECL = CDLL(dllpath)

# 64 Bits -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dllpath = '%s/MP300Com.dll' % str(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# MP300Dll = WinDLL(dllpath)
# MP300Dll_CDECL = CDLL(dllpath)

# Keyword Type definition ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WORD = c_ushort
DWORD = c_ulong
BYTE = c_ubyte

# Function Wrapped ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpc_AddToScenarioPcd = MP300Dll_CDECL.MPC_AddToScenarioPcd
mpc_AddToScenarioPcd.argtypes = [BYTE, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, 
                                 POINTER(BYTE), DWORD, POINTER(BYTE), POINTER(DWORD)]
mpc_AddToScenarioPcd.restype = WORD

# -- Creation of the First Pointer to the array of Bytes --------------------------------------------
array1 = (BYTE* len(5))(*[BYTE(1),BYTE(2),BYTE(3),BYTE(4),BYTE(5)])
array2 = (BYTE* len(5))(*[BYTE(10),BYTE(20),BYTE(30),BYTE(40),BYTE(50)])

# -- Pointer cast of the array1 and 2 ---------------------------------------------------------------
cast(array1, POINTER(BYTE))
cast(array2, POINTER(BYTE))
 
# VOID* obj creation --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
param = c_void_p()

# -- Function Usage through Python Code -------------------------------------------------------------
mpc_AddToScenarioPcd(BYTE(0),          
                     DWORD(0),           
                     (22),                       
                     DWORD(1),        
                     DWORD(1),       
                     DWORD(1),        
                     DWORD(1),             
                     DWORD(2),      
                     array1,               
                     DWORD(10),   
                     array2, 
                     param)
```

**With Python 3.4 (32-bits version) & DLL 32-bits**:

=> Everything is working well, no error.

**With Python 3.8 (64-bits version) & DLL 64-bits**:

=> I get this exception: **OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000005EC0B808**

I need to use a 64-bit version, consequently I'm blocked with this issue... If someone could explain to me what is wrong with my pointer (or type usage..) in 64-bits, and, how to solve it, I'll be very grateful!!

Again thank you very much in advance for all your expertise & work on my topic,

*PS: Sorry for the non functional code and the inability to reproduce the exception*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's sample DLL code and minimal `ctypes` code that works on both 32- and 64-bit Python.  Note the following points:

- There are pre-defined Windows types in `ctypes.wintypes`.
- When `.argtypes` and `.restype` are set correctly, number of parameters and types are checked and converted as needed between Python and C.  Extra casting and wrapping is not usually required.
- `CDLL` corresponds to 32-bit `__cdecl` calling convention.  `WinDLL` corresponds to 32-bit `__stdcall`.  In 64-bit, there is only one calling convention.  It is implemented differently between Linux and Windows, but still only one, so both `CDLL` and `WinDLL` will work, but use the correct one for 32-bit portability.

**test.c**

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
WORD mpc_AddToScenarioPcd(BYTE b, DWORD d1, DWORD d2, DWORD d3, DWORD d4, DWORD d5, DWORD d6, DWORD d7, LPBYTE pb1, DWORD d8, LPBYTE pb2, LPVOID pv) {
    printf("%hhu %u %u %u %u %u %u %u %p %u %p %p\n",b,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,pb1,d8,pb2,pv);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%hhu %hhu\n",pb1[i],pb2[i]);
    return 1234;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *  # pre-defined Windows types

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.mpc_AddToScenarioPcd.argtypes = BYTE,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,LPBYTE,DWORD,LPBYTE,LPVOID
dll.mpc_AddToScenarioPcd.restype = WORD

b1 = (BYTE * 5)(1,2,3,4,5)
b2 = (BYTE * 5)(10,20,30,40,50)
print(f'{addressof(b1):016X} {addressof(b2):016X}')
result = dll.mpc_AddToScenarioPcd(100,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,b1,8,b2,None)
print(result)
```

**Output**

Note the addresses printed in Python and C are the same.

```
00000194D0447A90 00000194D0447C10
100 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 00000194D0447A90 8 00000194D0447C10 0000000000000000
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5 50
1234
```

Comment: Hello @Mark Tolonen,

First, Thank you very much for your help & expertise on my topic !

I've updated this one with a Part 2, and issue with LPBYTE type. If you could get a glimpse into it I'll appreciate it very much ! :)

A summary will be that I get exceptions when I tried to directly pass array of c_ubyte to the C function expecting LPBYTE (everything detailled in Part 2 of my post).
I've tried to pass an array of byte or a byref, but nothing worked well.

Exception:
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 9: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_byte instance 
instead of c_ubyte_Array_2

Comment: @Ser I recommend asking a new question.  SO is meant to be one question, and editing a question changes the context of existing answers and comments.  You can rollback your change and ask a new question.

Comment: @Ser That said, your code edit isn't valid (`range(0,listofHexVal)` gives an error), and the  error message posted indicates it expected signed byte (c_byte vs. c_ubyte).  So make a new question with an [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I'll work as you suggested to avoid confusion and try to put a correct code example too !